# Film in which people can time-travel to relive the biggest world disasters; main character changes a destiny, saving many people

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, soft-sci-fi

I saw a film about 10 years ago. It was about people that could live the biggest disasters in the world that had happened again. They could travel in time and see these disasters. There were some plane crashes, metro crashes, *Titanic* disaster and so on.

But one man (positive main role) saw another bad man who was throwing a coin in the air and this coin fell down. This positive role changed a destiny and saved many people. This saving caused some damages to negative roles in this film.

Comment: Languag/nationality? Was the film new 10 years ago or old?

Comment: The way he described it I most definitely think it's Thrill Seekers / The Time Shifters.

Comment: I didn't know language or nationality. I remembered only the plot. Thanks DoctorWho22.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the movie you are talking about is called [*Thrill Seekers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Shifters) (1999), it's also known as *The Time Shifters*.

[image: original movie poster]

[The wikia](http://www.self.gutenberg.org/articles/The_Time_Shifters) states this.

> Tom Merrick (Van Dien) works as a TV reporter when he's nearly killed
>   in an accident while informing about a fire in the Evanston power
>   plant. After directing his crew to take another position he spots a
>   creepy-looking man, causing him to stay behind. This accidentally
>   saves his life as the crew is killed in the partial collapse of a
>   building.
>
> After some time, he decides to do some research on catastrophes for a
>   documentary he's preparing when he accidentally stumbles upon several
>   pictures of the man he saw at the power plant (Richings), who appears
>   to turn up in different disasters (sinking of Titanic, Hindenburg
>   disaster and hurricane Hugo) as far apart as 50 years, but who still
>   looks the same in all the pictures.
>
> As his boss Eleanor hopes for a good story she books Merrick a flight
>   to Washington, D.C. to get the original photographs from the author.
>   When on the plane, he again spots the man from the power plant
>   disaster and checks his luggage. He finds a flyer and discovers a
>   futuristic enterprise—Thrill Seekers—will make time travel possible in
>   the year 2070 and will sell trips to the past. These trips consist of
>   travellers going straight to a catastrophe right before it happens, so
>   they can experience the emotion but are able to travel back in time
>   again before they get killed.

The main character ends up using knowledge of future events to save people, including his own life.

> Which is worse, Merrick finds out that the Flight 222 he is on will be
>   involved in a mid-air collision, killing everyone on board.
>
> Thanks to that knowledge, Merrick forces the pilots to change the
>   course of action which saves a plane from crashing and killing
>   hundreds of people. The mysterious man disappears before landing.
>   Merrick is arrested by the FBI with the charge of plane hijacking
>   attempt. Agent Baker is sure about the hijacking attempt while his
>   younger assistant, Agent Stanton believes Merrick's story. However,
>   Merrick's knowledge of the future disasters causes the changes in the
>   future so the company Thrill Seekers sends two agents to the past to
>   stop Merrick.