# Trying to remember a movie with a time traveling man in black coat and a top hat

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie in the 90s when I was young.

The plot is fuzzy, but I believe it had the following:

Man and woman find a picture and there is a guy in a black coat always appearing in it. I think the time traveler was going back in time to stop disasters or creating them.

What is this movie?

Comment: This reminds me a bit of *[The Gathering](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheGathering)* but it was a 2001 film, with a group showing up, and it's tied to religion (they're spectators to the Crucifixion who are doomed to constantly witness disasters).

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Several Doctor Who (2005) episodes have references to the Doctor appearing throughout time. The one that comes to mind, though, is an early Matt Smith episode (I think?) and he didn't wear a black coat. Christopher Eccleston did, though. Memory is failing me as to when this episode was...

Comment: [Observers](https://fringe.fandom.com/wiki/Observers) in the Fringe series *almost* meet the criteria: time-travellers wearing black suits and hats, appearing at significant points in history.

Comment: @FreeMan If it's Doctor Who, it could be _Rose_ or _Aliens of London_, both of which reference whoisdoctorwho.co.uk (a conspiracy theory website devoted to anachronistic photographic and anecdotal evidence of the Doctor's shenanigans).

Comment: That's what I was thinking of @wizzwizz4! Thanks for the reminder. I have a funny feeling that's not what the OP is looking for, though, especially since he wouldn't have seen either of these episodes 10 years before they were aired. Unless, of course, The Doctor is now going by the moniker "WhatIsIt"... :D

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit late in the 1990s, and he wears more a bowler than a top hat, but this could be *[Thrill Seekers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrill_Seekers_(film))* from 1999.

> Tom Merrick (Van Dien) is a TV reporter filming a live segment on a fire at a power plant. He spots a creepy-looking man (Richings), causing him to move away from his crew. This accidentally saves his life as the crew is killed in the partial collapse of a building. After the accident, Merrick gives up his job as a reporter and begins working for a magazine.
>
> In June 2000, while researching catastrophes, Merrick finds several pictures of the man from the power plant, who appears to turn up in different disasters (sinking of Titanic, Hindenburg disaster and Hurricane Hugo), but who still looks the same in all the pictures. Merrick's boss Eleanor books him a flight to Washington, D.C. to get the original photographs. On the plane, he spots the man from the power plant and photos and checks his luggage. He finds a flyer and discovers a future enterprise – Thrill Seekers – will make time travel possible in the year 2070 and will sell trips to the past to allow travelers to visit a catastrophe before it occurs, but are able to travel back in time again before they get killed. Merrick finds out that the flight he is on will be involved in a mid-air collision, killing everyone on board.

[image: Confronting Murray Trevor, the black-clad time tourist]

[image: Cropped still from the trailer showing the images of Murray]

### Trailer

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53469/film-in-which-people-can-time-travel-to-relive-the-biggest-world-disasters-main/53470#53470

Comment: That's not a top hat.

Comment: @Valorum: ^_^ True, but I figured it was close enough.